# rust warp won't compile after switching filter orders

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I have 3 filters, if I combine them in order `a,c,b`, the code compiles. But if I switch their orders like `a,b,c`, the code won't compile. The filter seems the same to me. Why?

```
use reqwest::Method;
use serde_json::Value;
use warp::http::{HeaderMap, StatusCode};
use warp::path::FullPath;
use warp::reply::Response;
use std::convert::Infallible;
use warp::{Filter, Reply};

async fn fn_with_params_no_body(method: Method, path: FullPath, headers: HeaderMap, query: String) -> Result<Response, Infallible> {
    Ok(StatusCode::OK.into_response())
}

async fn fn_no_params_no_body(method: Method, path: FullPath, headers: HeaderMap) -> Result<Response, Infallible> {
    Ok(StatusCode::OK.into_response())
}

async fn fn_no_params_with_body(method: Method, path: FullPath, headers: HeaderMap, body: Value) -> Result<Response, Infallible> {
    Ok(StatusCode::OK.into_response())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ep0 = warp::any()
        .and(warp::method())
        .and(warp::path::full())
        .and(warp::header::headers_cloned())
        .and(warp::query::raw())
        .and_then(fn_with_params_no_body);

    let ep1 = warp::any()
        .and(warp::method())
        .and(warp::path::full())
        .and(warp::header::headers_cloned())
        .and_then(fn_no_params_no_body);

    let ep2 = warp::any()
        .and(warp::method())
        .and(warp::path::full())
        .and(warp::header::headers_cloned())
        .and(warp::body::json())
        .and_then(fn_no_params_with_body);

    let routes = ep0.or(ep2).or(ep1); // this would compile
    // let routes = ep0.or(ep1).or(ep2); // this won't
    warp::serve(routes)
        .run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 8080))
        .await
}
```

It says `expected struct Rejection, found enum Infallible` and `or` requires `Self: Filter<Error = Rejection> + Sized`, then why can I compile it after swithcing orders, none of the handle functions returns `Result<Response, Reject>`

```
   --> exproxy/src/main.rs:43:30
    |
43  |     let routes = ep0.or(ep1).or(ep2);
    |                              
    |
note: required by a bound in `or`
   --> /Users/ynx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.3.2/src/filter/mod.rs:140:22
    |
140 |         Self: Filter<Error = Rejection> + Sized,
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `or`
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. When `ep1` is called, it ends with `fn_with_params_no_body` so it returns either `Infalliable` or `Response`. In the order that works, first the `ep0` is checked, and if the route has parameters, it succeeds and doesn't keep going down the `or` chain. This means that the numbers after it will be sure that the route has no parameters. When `ep2` is reached, it can be sure that the input will have no routes, so it only bothers to check for the body. If it has a body, then it will succeed and stop the chain. Only if it's certain that the route has no route or body, `ep1` is run. Since it's the last one, and it's already known that there is no body or route (or else the previous functions would have worked) `ep1` is guaranteed to return a `Infalliable`. Any other order runs the risk of not returning an `Infalliable`, or as your error happened, passing a value that is already `Infalilliable` to one of the filters